# jqGrid data does not display data in MVC4 with json

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am a new to jqGrid. I tried to create simple example where controller returns a json object that contains model's array data. Web page displays the grid with the column names. Data itself does not appear.

Thanks for your help. I have been trying since three days.

**Here is my Controller**

```
List<ClientInvoice> clientInvoices = new List<ClientInvoice>
            {
                new ClientInvoice { Id=1, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 2111.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=2, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=3, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=4, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=5, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=6, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=7, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=8, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 21.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=9, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=11, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 200.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=12, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=13, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=14, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 200.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=15, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=16, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=17, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 200.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=18, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=19, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=21, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 200.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=22, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=23, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=24, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 200.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=25, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=26, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=27, Name = "test", Note = "note", Amount = 200.00f, Tax = 10.00f, Total = 210.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=28, Name = "test2", Note = "note2", Amount = 300.00f, Tax = 20.00f, Total = 320.00f},
                new ClientInvoice { Id=29, Name = "test3", Note = "note3", Amount = 400.00f, Tax = 30.00f, Total = 430.00f},


            };

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            //use Serialize method to convert patient list to json string

            string clientInvoiceJson = serializer.Serialize(clientInvoices);
            ViewBag.ClientInvoicesJson = clientInvoiceJson;
```

**And the view looks like this**

```
<input type="hidden" id="clientInvoices" value="@ViewBag.ClientInvoicesJson" />
<table id="list47"></table>
<div id="plist47"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var mydata1 = $("#clientInvoices").attr("value");
    var mydata = mydata1;
    jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        datatype: 'json',
        height: 150,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 60 },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Amount', index: 'Amount', width: 80 },
            { name: 'Tax', index: 'Tax', width: 80 },
            { name: 'Total', index: 'Total', width: 80 },
            { name: 'Note', index: 'Note', width: 150 }
        ],
        pager: "#plist47",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing jsonReader add this to your grid option

```
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "Id"

                },
```

Why are you invoking the server method in a separate function and assigning the response in variable  var mydata = mydata1;

instead of that use url in grid option to invoke the server method

```
url:'your_url_which_invoke_server_method',
```

Comment: jsonReader:{} did not help. I will try with url as you mentioned. I need to figure out how jqGrid call will look like inside the script. Thanks for your response.